# c:set tag to set a non-primitive type value

Tags: java, jstl

What's a possible way to use Spring Security tag `<sec:authentication property="principal.id" />` as the value for the `<c:set…>` tag?

These statements:

```
<c:set var="userId" value="<sec:authentication property='principal.id' />"/>
<c:set var="userId" value="<sec:authentication property=\"principal.id\" />"/>
```

won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to use «value» attribute in your case. Use `<c:set>` tag in this way:

```
<c:set var="userId">
    <sec:authentication property="principal.id"/>
</c:set>
```